# Code works in jsfiddle But not Lamp Localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, checkbox

I am super frustrated right now because I have some code that works correctly on jsfiddle and not on my local host..

Here is the link to my jsfiddle page. The goal is to be able to specify how many checkbox's can be selected at once, and also to have them animated well via css as you see on this jsfiddle page.
http://jsfiddle.net/SQdNQ/195/

In order to test it on my local host, I Completely stripped down everything on my page aside of just the absolute things I needed for this to work and then even made my css and Js Inline to illustrate better.

Here is the exact code from my test.php page in localhost

```
<html>
<head>

<!--CSS To Make Check Box's Look Good-->    
<style type="text/css">
.example{
  margin-bottom : 1.5em;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old),
input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
  width     : 2em;
  margin    : 0;
  padding   : 0;
  font-size : 1em;
  opacity   : 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-left  : -2em;
  line-height  : 1.5em;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label > span,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label > span{
  display          : inline-block;
  width            : 0.875em;
  height           : 0.875em;
  margin           : 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(192,192,192);
  border-radius    : 0.25em;
  background       : rgb(224,224,224);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  vertical-align   : bottom;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old):checked + label > span{
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span:before{
  content     : '✓';
  display     : block;
  width       : 1em;
  color       : rgb(153,204,102);
  font-size   : 0.875em;
  line-height : 1em;
  text-align  : center;
  text-shadow : 0 0 0.0714em rgb(115,153,77);
  font-weight : bold;
}

input[type=radio]:not(old):checked +  label > span > span{
  display          : block;
  width            : 0.5em;
  height           : 0.5em;
  margin           : 0.125em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(115,153,77);
  border-radius    : 0.125em;
  background       : rgb(153,204,102);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
}
<!--End Of CSS-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='toppingtypes']").change(function () {
        var maxAllowed = 2;
        var cnt = $("input[name='toppingtypes']:checked").length;
        if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
            $(this).prop("checked", "");
            alert('You can select  ' + maxAllowed + ' Toppings');
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head>
</body>
<!--Pizza Toppings Types Start-->
<li id="pizzatoppingtypes">

    <div class="title-wrapper">
        <h2>Select Your Pizza Toppings</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="submit.php" name="toppingtypes" id="contact-form">  
        <div id="main">
            <div class="example">
              <div>
                <input id="bacon" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="1" /><label style="color:black" for="bacon"><span><span></span></span>Bacon</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="bananapeppers" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="2" /><label style="color:black" for="bananapeppers"><span><span></span></span>Banana Peppers</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="blackolives" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="3" /><label style="color:black" for="blackolives"><span><span></span></span>Black Olives</label>
              </div>        
              <div>
                <input id="extracheese" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="4" /><label style="color:black" for="extracheese"><span><span></span></span>Extra Cheese</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="greenpeppers" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="5" /><label style="color:black" for="greenpeppers"><span><span></span></span>Green Peppers</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="ham" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="6" /><label style="color:black" for="ham"><span><span></span></span>Ham</label>
              </div>    
              <div>
                <input id="hamburger" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="7" /><label style="color:black" for="hamburger"><span><span></span></span>Hamburger</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="italiansausage" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="8" /><label style="color:black" for="italiansausage"><span><span></span></span>Italian Sausage</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="jalapenopeppers" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="9" /><label style="color:black" for="jalapenopeppers"><span><span></span></span>Jalapeno Peppers</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="cannedmushrooms" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="10" /><label style="color:black" for="cannedmushrooms"><span><span></span></span>Canned Mushrooms</label>
              </div>             
             <div>
                <input id="freshmushrooms" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="11" /><label style="color:black" for="freshmushrooms"><span><span></span></span>Fresh Mushrooms</label>
              </div>        
              <div>
                <input id="onions" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="12" /><label style="color:black" for="onions"><span><span></span></span>Onions</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="pepperoni" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="13" /><label style="color:black" for="pepperoni"><span><span></span></span>Pepperoni</label>
              </div>    
              <div>
                <input id="pineapple" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="14" /><label style="color:black" for="pineapple"><span><span></span></span>Pineapple</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="slicedsmokedsausage" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="15" /><label style="color:black" for="slicedsmokedsausage"><span><span></span></span>Sliced Smoked Sausage</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="tomatoes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="16" /><label style="color:black" for="tomatoes"><span><span></span></span>Tomatoes</label>
              </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div> 
</li>
<!--Pizza Toppings Types End--> 

</body>
</html>
```

Please test it yourself on your lamp/mamp/wamp server and see if you have any better luck.

Thanks again!

Comment: where are you calling your jquery libraries? these are included in your jsfiddle, but not in code above

Comment: Are `<!--` comments allowed inside `<style>` blocks?

Comment: Also, set your doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: There's something called a console in the browser, you can hit F12 to open it, and it will show what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're not including a jQuery reference in your script.

Include this in your header:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

to use the CDN, or download the jQuery script and reference it manually.

Comment: Ha that worked for the stripped version, but my real page already had jquery called and is not working. There are quite a few different jquery libs called in it. So perhaps I need to strip one thing at a time to find out which one is not making it work. Thanks for the help. I will Post my full webpage if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle works because `jQuery` is included.
You forgot to include `jQuery` on your `localhost` Code.

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
the rest of your html...
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to what Pheonixblade9 and Pedro Lobito correctly identify as the likely problem, another common mistake is to open the website via file access in the browser, something like this:

```
file:///c:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
```

If that's what you're doing, try this instead:

```
localhost
```

Just that.